# Why ethyl cyanide and propanol have the same boiling point?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, boiling-point, hydrogen-bond

As I understand, the intermolecular forces of ethyl cyanide are of van der Waals nature (dipole-dipole) but in the propanol molecule there are hydrogen bonds which are in principle much stronger. Why then their boiling points are equal (97 ºC)? Their molar mass is very similar too.

Obviously, the triple bond of the cyanide group must be the cause, but I do not know how it can affect the boiling point, as the C-N bond is less polar than the O-H bond.

Comment: Van der Waals bonds usually describe a different class of (weaker) interactions than dipole-dipole interactions (ultimately *induced* dipole interactions between molecules that don't have strong dipolar features). Whether this is a factor here where both molecules have strong dipoles is less clear.

Comment: @matt_black  The term [van der Waals force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force)  *...... is sometimes used loosely for all intermolecular forces. The term always includes the London dispersion force between instantaneously induced dipoles. It is sometimes applied to the Debye force between a permanent dipole and a corresponding induced dipole or to the Keesom force between permanent molecular dipoles.*

Comment: It goes in the direction of being a coincidence. You can ask the same question for a huge number of pairs of substances. All you need is picking up values from tables or literature. That is because you have a number of factors (even interconnected) which contributes to the phase diagram. From molecular mass to molecular shape, from packing to polarity, etc. In the specific case, cyanide molecules are quite polar. CN is an electron withdrawing group, you should look at its effect on the whole molecule.

Comment: Use the term propiononitrile rather than ethyl cyanide lest someone gets the idea it is toxic in the sense of cyanide.

Comment: @Alchimista it is correct that this kind of similarities can be found searching through data tables but even so, it is interesting to know why this happens. Some days ago I posted a question asking why hydrogen bonds are stronger than VW forces. After, explaining this to my high school students, I used randomly a polar molecule like ethyl cyanide to illustrate the VW forces and ethanol for hydrogen bond and I got the surprise. Now I know that I need to be more careful regarding this general statements about intermolecular forces like hydrogen bonds are always stronger than VW forces.

Comment: I mean that you cannot really know why it happens without perhaps modelling and calculating a lot for each couple. I did mention tables not as an activity, but to say that one can find similar boiling points or melting points for a multitude of molecules, even belonging different classes. As for there is nothing that alone determine such properties.

Comment: And, as you are a teacher, in the case you proposed and for those purpose, it is not important how much che CN bond are polar, but how much the molecule is.

Comment: Yes, I just found that the dipolar moment of the ethyl cyanide (propiononitrile) is 4,04 Debye, almos 2,5 times higher than propanol's... this may be the most important factor, I think, to explain its high boiling point.

Comment: @fich good. Glad it helped.